# How to avoid the repaint effect when using the UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I was debugging an issue with a view controller recently and noticed that each time I drag the view up or down it will repaint the entire contents of my UITableView (as it calls the cellForRowAtIndexPath method each time).  Is it possible to use an in memory datasource or add another delegate to my view controller so it won't repaint each time?

I'm not modifying anything inside the cells when the user interacts with it so my data source would be static after the initial "viewDidLoad" is called.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

  if ([self.hats count] > 0) {
    //do some complex stuff in here that hurts each time we re-draw this ...
  }

    return cell;  
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: post the code of the complex stuff. Cells aren't saved. Once they move offscreen they get in the reuse bin, and when they become visible they have to be redrawn.

Comment: I don't have the full src but basically I create a UIView and add that to the subview of the cell. But before this step I add a few other controls to the UIView (dynamic) and then release them all.  It just feels painful to reload these. Thought a delegate or technique might exist for static data sources like this to avoid the perf hit

Comment: you see, that's the problem. all the subview adding stuff goes into if (cell == nil) { // here }. If you do it right you can add dozens of views without performance impact

Comment: I wanted to say should go into if (cell==nil)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so `// complex stuff` means adding UIViews.

I make an example for an UIImageView. Since you don't show the complex stuff you have to adopt it on your own.

your code looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if ([self.hats count] > 0) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView....];
        [cell.contentView addSubView:imageView];
        [imageView setImage:foo];
        [imageView release];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

refactor your code that it looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView....];
        [cell.contentView addSubView:imageView];
        imageView.tag = 42;
        [imageView release];
    }

    if ([self.hats count] > 0) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [cell viewWithTag:42];
        [imageView setImage:foo];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

et voila, your tableview is responsive. Because you create the subviews exactly one time for each cell. And when the cell isn't used anymore and goes into the reuse bin the subviews stay with it.

And if you need 4 imageViews in one cell and 8 in another, you add 8 imageviews when you create the cell and give them a frame of CGRectZero and of course a different tag for each view.
If you need them you show them, if you don't need them you set the image to nil and the frame to zero.

Comment: Any reason why I would go inside the first if statement each time I move the view around? shouldn't cell already have a value as you mentioned and skip this after the initial setup?

Comment: Instead of using this line "UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];" should I instead use this one? "UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];"

Comment: @Toran Billups If you use a custom cell (ie loaded from a nib) make sure you set the correct CellIdentifier. When a cell won't get reused it's most likely because the reuse identifiers of the created cell and the identifier used for dequeueing don't match.

Comment: I'm not actually loading a "custom" cell unless that means just having a XIB with a single UITableView.  Also how can I determine what the CellIdentifier should be to get the reuse here? Can I NSLog something to get started or? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Or is it possible that I need to set the Identifier field in Interface Builder for the UITableView itself? Not sure if this exists w/out a custom cell defined (as I only have a single UITableView - not a custom cell)

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: **CellIdentifier** ]; /**/
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: **CellIdentifier** ] autorelease];
The bolded NSString instances have to match for a successful reuse

Comment: got it - so my last question would be do I need to set this identifier in IB for this to match correctly at runtime? and if so can I set this on a UITableView alone (no other elements in the view) ? thanks for all the help on this!

Comment: the cellidentifier belongs to a UITableViewCell. If you don't have a custom cell in your xib file there is no need to set it in IB. If you create a Cell in a xib there is a "Identifier" field in the first tab of the inspector. The value of this field is used when you load the cell from IB instead of using [initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:]

Comment: So as I don't have a custom cell what should this "CellIdentifier" be in objective-c to get the valid reuse? Because currently "Cell" isn't working :(

Comment: Does it matter that inside the if I also create another UIView and add a few controls to that before adding it to the subview of the cell?

Comment: For anyone else who comes along the fix for the reuse cell problem was that I had defined a method to declare the height of the cell in code rather than using the IB property. So after I removed this it was able to reuse the cells - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return 70;
}